# How to flat tree, auto generation parent?

Tags: javascript, tree

I want to keep the parent-child relationship of the tree node.

I have a JSON tree, like this

```
{
  id: null,
  children: [
    {
     id: 1,
     children: [
        { 
         id: 11,
         children: [
            {
             id: 111
             children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
         id: '12',
         children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
     id: '2',
     children: [
        { 
          id: '21',
          children: []
        },
        { 
          id: '22',
          children: [
            {
              id: '221',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want flat the tree, like this

```
[
  { id: 1, parent: null,},
  { id: 11, parent: 1, },
  { id: 111, parent: 11, },
  { id: 2, parent: null, },
  { id: 21, parent: 2, },
  ...
]
```

parent automatic generated

Is there any good way?

Comment: have you tried anything? what goes wrong?

Comment: Before that, I didn't know flatMap.Many attempts have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` method and create recursive function that will return 1D array as a result.

```js
const data = {"id":null,"children":[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":11,"children":[{"id":111,"children":[]}]},{"id":"12","children":[]}]},{"id":"2","children":[{"id":"21","children":[]},{"id":"22","children":[{"id":"221","children":[]}]}]}]}

const flatten = (data, parent = null) => 
  data.flatMap(({ id, children }) => ([
    { id, parent }, 
    ...flatten(children, id)
  ]))
 

const result = flatten(data.children);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the object and return an array of the flat children.

```js
const
    getFlat = ({ id, children = [] }) =>
        children.flatMap(o => [{ id: o.id, parent: id }, ...getFlat(o)]);

var data = { id: null, children: [{ id: 1, children: [{ id: 11, children: [{ id: 111, children: [] }] }, { id: '12', children: [] }] }, { id: '2', children: [{ id: '21', children: [] }, { id: '22', children: [{ id: '221', children: [] }] }] }] },
    flat = getFlat(data);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will take @nenad Vracar's answer

Answer (score 0):

If compatbility with [Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap) is important, then the following approach which avoids the need for `Array#flatMap` might suit:

```js
const input={id:null,children:[{id:'1',children:[{id:'11',children:[{id:'111',children:[]}]},{id:'12',children:[]}]},{id:'2',children:[{id:'21',children:[]},{id:'22',children:[{id:'221',children:[]}]}]}]};

const result = [];

// Define recursive function to walk through the data tree
// and produce a flat array of required data
const recurse = (item, parent) => {

  // Only add item to result if it has valid id
  if (item.id) {
    result.push({
      id: item.id,
      parent: parent ? parent.id : null
    });
  }
  
  // Iterate the children of this item, traversing and
  // processing them in the same way
  item.children.forEach(child => recurse(child, item))
}

recurse(input);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will take @nenad Vracar's answer

Comment: Browser compatibility is not considered here

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple recursion to achieve this

```
let data = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'a1',
      children: [{
         id: 2,
         name: 'a2',
         children: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'b1',
            children: []
         },
         {
            id: 4,
            name: 'b2',
            children: []
         }
        ]
     }]
   }

function flatten(data){
    output = [];
    return (function indentHandler(data, level, parent){
        output.push({id: data['id'], parent: parent})
        if (data['children'].length === 0){
            return output;
        }
        level += 1;
        data['children'].forEach(function(child){
            return indentHandler(child, level, data.name);
        }); 
        return output;
    })(data, 0, null);
   }

flatten(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will take @nenad Vracar's answer

Answer (score 0):

use recursion

```js
var tree = {
  id: null,
  children: [{
      id: 1,
      children: [{
          id: 11,
          children: [{
            id: 111,
            children: []
          }]
        },
        {
          id: '12',
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      children: [{
          id: '21',
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: '22',
          children: [{
            id: '221',
            children: []
          }]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var flat = [];

function flatArray(arr, parentId) {

  arr.forEach(function(el) {

    flat.push({
      id: el.id,
      parent: parentId || null
    });

    if (el.children)
      flatArray(el.children, el.id);
  });
}

flatArray(tree.children, 0)

console.log(flat);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will take @nenad Vracar's answer